# c# winforms how to disable the scrollbar of richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a customized scrollbar, however i have tried my best to make the original one from windows invisible by using the customized one covering on it, it can not be done.

any one have idea of how remove the original scrollbar ?

Comment: And (how) did you attach the custom bar to the RichEdit?

Comment: i use one user control which contain a panel and a customized scrollbar. Then  add a richtextbox  to the panel.

Answer (score 6):

```
this.richTextBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
```

Comment: Yup.  Just setting the value in the Property grid would suffice.

Comment: @prophet, aren't you looking at the UC scrollbar?

Comment: rightnow , the original scroll bar hides in most case but when i dragging my customized scroll, that scroll bar appears again and the richtext box flicker frequently.